# Distinguir acentos y no acentos en MySQL y Java

Tags: java, mysql

He creado una tabla en una base MySQL que almacena un campo de texto:

```
CREATE TABLE `Usuarios` (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

He introducido 2 nombres: José y jose

Y desde Java hago una consulta de búsqueda que me dice que tengo dos registros iguales:

```
ResultSet resultado = consulta.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Usuarios` WHERE UPPER(`Nombre`) = ‘JOSÉ’";
resultado.first();
System.out.println("Usuarios llamados JOSÉ: " + resultado.getInt(1));
```

**RESPUESTA: Usuarios llamados JOSÉ: 2**

¿Cómo puedo evitar que trate por igual vocales acentuadas y no acentuadas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacerlo con  `utf8_bin`, para ello se utiliza la palabra reservada `COLLATE`. Con este `charset` le estamos indicando a MySQL que la comparación en la búsqueda la haga a nivel binario, con lo cual ahora sí podrá distinguir entre palabras con acentos y sin acentos, mayúsculas y minúsculas, sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE `nombre` = 'josé' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Obtenido de aquí:

[aquí](https://phpsblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/distinguir-acentos-mayusculas-y-minusculas-en-mysql/)

Comment: Aparece el error: COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que el `COLLATION` de la tabla estaba establecido de forma predeterminada en `utf8_general_ci`. `_ci` significa case insensitive. Cambiándolo por `utf8_bin` se soluciona. Información sacada del [manual de MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Para cambiar sólo una tabla tenemos que hacer esto:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Y para cambiar toda la base de datos:

```
ALTER SCHEMA baseDatos DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin;
```